# How to install libdl.so on linux contianers?

Tags: asp.net, linux, visual-studio, docker, libdl

I am using Visual Studio .net Core with Linux Docker Contianers.
I am attempting to use dlopen, which is part of the libdl.so library.
I get:

> DllNotFoundException

.

Unable to load shared library `libdl.so` or one of its dependencies

I was going to download the .so somewhere and put it in the execution path. Unfortunately I could not find a straight copy of `libdl.so`.

Is there some way to include this library? Maybe a Nuget package 
Thanks

Comment: It’s a standard part of the system C library.  What’s your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE #####
EXPOSE #####

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY XXXX/XXXX.csproj XXXX/
COPY XXXX.XXXX/XXXX.XXXX.XXXX XXXX.XXXX/
COPY XXXX.XXXX/XXXX.XXXX.XXXX XXXX.XXXX/
COPY XXXX/XXXX.XXXX.XXXX XXXX/
RUN dotnet restore CalcAPI/CalcAPI.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/XXXX
RUN dotnet build XXXX.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish XXXX.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXXX.dll"]

Comment: Edit your question to include the Dockerfile with correct formatting please.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75855053/how-to-address-crash-due-to-missing-libdl-so-on-ubuntu-22