# How to address crash due to missing libdl.so on Ubuntu 22?

Tags: linux, dll, glibc, dynamic-linking

Applications crashing on Ubuntu 22

```
user@machine:~$ myapp
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.dlopen(String fileName, Int32 flags)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.<.cctor>g__OnResolveDllImport|46_0(String libraryName, Assembly assembly, Nullable`1 searchPath) in /tmp/tmp9xcr_e_u/pythonnet/2.5.1+ahl1/ws/src/src/runtime/runtime.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.NativeLibrary.LoadLibraryCallbackStub(String libraryName, Assembly assembly, Boolean hasDllImportSearchPathFlags, UInt32 dllImportSearchPathFlags)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs) in /tmp/tmp9xcr_e_u/pythonnet/2.5.1+ahl1/ws/src/src/runtime/runtime.cs:line 195
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs) in /tmp/tmp9xcr_e_u/pythonnet/2.5.1+ahl1/ws/src/src/runtime/pythonengine.cs:line 179
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs) in /tmp/tmp9xcr_e_u/pythonnet/2.5.1+ahl1/ws/src/src/runtime/pythonengine.cs:line 156
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt() in /tmp/tmp9xcr_e_u/pythonnet/2.5.1+ahl1/ws/src/src/runtime/pythonengine.cs:line 266
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is an issue to do with `libdl.so` missing, probably a system library. How do I install it or otherwise resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: This is a building issue with the application, the application was incorrectly built and linked against libdl.so. For Linux support, the software must be rebuilt and linked to libdl.so.2 instead.**

In this specific stack trace, the crash is in the C# pythonnet stack, fixed in pythonnet >= 3.0

**More Explanation:**

This is the standard glibc library. It's often linked automatically when binaries are created or it's often hardcoded in specific builds (the library is used to load further libraries).

The library is `libdl.so.2` in Linux distributions (Debian, RHEL, Ubuntu, etc...). It was historically `libdl.so` in older operating systems and Unix variants.

Both have been coexisting for a while and causing confusion:

- On CentOS, libdl.so can be installed by `sudo yum install glibc-devel`
- On Debian and Ubuntu <=20, libdl.so can be installed by `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`
- On Ubuntu >= 22, libdl.so no longer exists, it can't be installed by libc6-dev (nor gcc).

The dev glibc package is a transitive dependency of gcc. It's very common for gcc to be installed on Linux machines (developer machines and end-user machines alike), so it's very common for `libdl.so` to be accidentally available. It's not part of the base operating system and should not be expected to be available.

Software that have been linked to libdl.so will crash when the library is not available. It's a long standing issue. It's getting more noticeable due to Ubuntu 22 lately, it was only noticeable in containers and minimal OS install before (no gcc).

In this specific stack trace, the crash was in the C# pythonnet stack, the linking was fixed in pythonnet >= 3.0

Comment: Excellent answer, but what are users of Ubuntu >= 22 supposed to do? Or is it just that you have to change any mention of libdl.so to `libdl.so.2` ? Tnx!

Comment: You have to change any mention of libdl.so to libdl.so.2 and rebuild. It requires the source code and build toolchain, it's not necessarily something that end-users can do.

Comment: Groan! Thanks very much for the feedback. Is this change debated in the Ubuntu developers forums? Seems crazy. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having this libdl.so issue on a Debian 12 system. I guess it has caught up to Ubuntu... as installing libc6-dev does not solve the issue... For now I've created a symbolic link by hand: libdl.so -> libdl.so.2