# .net MIP SDK on Ubuntu 2204 fails to load libraries

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-7.0, ubuntu-22.04, microsoft-information-protection

Current setup:

- Running on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-jammy container (Ubuntu 2204)
- .net 7.0
- Microsoft.InformationProtection.File.Ubuntu2204 Version "1.14.108"
- Installed all dependencies mentioned in [sample application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSDK-File-Dotnet)
  `sudo apt-get install scons libgsf-1-dev libssl-dev libsecret-1-dev freeglut3-dev libcpprest-dev libcurl3-dev uuid-dev`

I am attempting to run MIP sdk to read confidential files in my company in backend code. I tested it with Windows setup and it works, however, running MIP sdk code on Unix systems which we use in Azure doesn't work.

1. Library is compiled for wrong operating system, because it's referencing `libdl.so`. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75855054) post clearly states, `libdl.so` is no longer available in Ubuntu 2204 and application should reference `libdl.so.2`. Application fails with the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/linux/native/libdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.14/libdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/libdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/linux/native/liblibdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.14/liblibdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/liblibdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/linux/native/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.14/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/runtimes/linux/native/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.14/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      /workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

By adding the link `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so`, I was able to work around this issue temporarily, but it's not ideal by any stretch.

2. After adding a link to previously missing library, I am greeted with a new error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): LoadLibrary failed for: [/workspace/RestAPI/bin/Debug/net7.0/libmip_dotnet.so]
         at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.SafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String dllToLoad)
         at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls(String dllFolder, String dllName, String[] dllDependencies)
         at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize(MipComponent mipComponent, String path)
         at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.CreateMipContext(MipConfiguration mipConfiguration)
```

Here I am completely stuck. Even attempted at running a c snippet from this suggestion in [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSDK-File-Dotnet/issues/2#issuecomment-1232900404), but I got this error. I tried all kinds of paths, copying the files close and nothing worked here.

```
err = ./libmip_dotnet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

All resources I found online failed me. Maybe someone has some bright ideas how to fix this or how to get in touch with the team to fix this library?

Answer (score 0):

I thought we fixed this issue, but it may not have been released. I’ll follow up with the engineering folks on Monday.

Edit: The libdl.so.2 issue has been fixed and will be released in January.

I can't repro the other issue you're seeing with a sample application unless I rename or delete libmip_dotnet.so. Is libmip_dotnet.so in the same directory as the executable?

Here's a link to my dockerfile with a modified version of the File SDK .NET sample.

https://gist.github.com/tommoser/ee3adaed016dc7086557c35b4e2548d9

You can get the modified sample from this branch: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSDK-File-Dotnet/tree/major-update

I'll update docs later but thought this might be helpful to test. Update the appsettings.json with your clientId, tenantId, and app secret (just for testing). Then you can run ./mipsdk -l in the container or as part of the build to see what happens.

If the .so file is *not* in the app directory, you can try using the optional path param on MIP.Initialize.

`MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File, "/app/so_files");`

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I'll try it out once I get some time. Quick question about `MIP.Initialize` - by browsing the code, I noticed that it's not necessary to add this unless  I want to actually change the path to libraries, since it's called anyway. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, it's only required if you're changing the library path. Otherwise, it should load from the local executable folder.

Comment: Hey, we have been waiting for a fix for a while now, any update on this?